# Have select() and/or pluck() been broken in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

The following code does not pluck the name column of the selected `user` record. Rather, returns the entire row. Before I make a re-creatable example: Is this the expected behaviour here?

*I want to explicitly select columns across joins to reduce my JSON payload size, and to return a nested model hierarchy to my clients.*

I should add that I'm experiencing the same behaviour when using the `pluck()` function as well, on the same line. Perhaps I've done something wrong.

There's tons of examples showing this approach with earlier versions of Laravel. **Version 6 may have broken this.**

```
$query = Post::whereHas('user.address', function ($query) use ($lat, $lon, $distance) {
    $query->distance($lat, $lon, $distance);
})->with([
    'user' => function ($query) {    
        $query->select('name'); // TODO: Report this bug. I've also tried pluck()
    },
    'user.address' => function ($query) use ($lat, $lon, $distance) {
        $query->distance($lat, $lon, $distance);
    },
    'user.address.city',
    'bids' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('amount', 'DESC');
    },
    'bids.user',
    'images',
]);
```

Comment: Try with this notation `Post::with('user:id,name')->get();`

Comment: As per the comment above, you must include the relationship key in the query or else it will return nothing. You can also look into the serialization methods to trim JSON output instead of writing complex queries. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization

Answer (score 2):

`pluck()` is a collection method, it executes the query and returns a simple Collection object of the field you specify.

Using `pluck()` inside your subquery builder executes it (returning nothing, because you are assigning it to nothing) while the `$query` variable is unmodified and behaves as normal returning all columns.

If you were to dump the value of the `pluck()` inside this query, you would see it is an array of just names, and because of that, it has no affect on the query itself.

```php
'user' => function ($query) {    
        dd($query->pluck('name'));
    }
```

`select()` should work fine in this case. You just need to also provide the relationship key or else it will just return a null object.

```php
'user' => function ($query) {    
        $query->select(['id', 'name']); 
    },
```

Comment: Hi @Darryl, confirming including the relationship key(s) was the solution. Thanks so much. In regards to your comment on serialization: I'm favouring complex queries to minimize strain on the garbage collector, and serializer. I don't want any more properties in memory than need be.

Comment: I marked this too soon. Unfortunately it's not working on nested relationships like `user.address`

Comment: From your original code, it would appear you need to make sure you select the address id, and city id and according to the (I'm assuming this is what you're using) Laravel Geographical docs, the `select()` needs to precede the `distance()` call.